# How to rewrite htaccess 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am developing a raw PHP web application. But, I am facing problem when I use invalid words after url (just for check).

**Current htaccess code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404
Options -Indexes
```

**For Example:**

I need https://example.com/profile (without extension). Which is now working with the following htaccess code. When I hit https://example.com/profile/lllflfl (`lllflfl` is invalid words, just for check 404 error) it's goes to 404 error page. Which is also good. But, when I hit https://example.com/profile.php/lllflfl then my website still display current page (current page means https://example.com/profile this page). I think this need to redirect 404 page. What is your thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: `/file.php/foo/bar` points to `/file.php` because `/foo/bar` (traling  path after a filename) is part of PATH INFO. It's enabled on apache by default.  you can disable it using the following line in htacess `AcceptPathInfo Off` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the suggestion by `@starkeen` which is very vital you could do this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(php|html|htm)/.*$ - [L,R=404]
```

and let them treated as error requests.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^profile.php/.*$ /404pagehere.php [L]
```

Comment: Now `profile.php` loading from the sub-folder called `admin`. My current url is https://example.com/admin/profile. Also `profile.php` is a sample page. I have too much page like this (e.g: dashboard, add_user, user_list etc). And `400.php` is located in the root folder. Then what is the **RewriteRule** for this?

Comment: Adjust everything we gave you to have admin/ after the ^ symbol

Comment: This is not working. Still I can see the broken after use invalid works end of url. I hit the http://prntscr.com/j1dosh for see my current file listing. Currently I used `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/*$ 404.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://st.dev.krazyit.com.au/404
Options -Indexes`